# Eazfuscator.NET does not merge zedgraph.dll

Tags: c#, merge, zedgraph, eazfuscator

I used zedgrzph.dll in my application and after building, it works fine. I use Eazfuscator.NET for merging dll with application exe. After merging, I get warnning below from Eazfuscator.NET.

> WARNING  Assembly at file path "C:\Users\New folder\ZedGraph.dll" should be signed with a key to work properly after obfuscation. Please use 'key-file' or 'key-container' option.
> Alternatively, .snk key file can be placed near the input assembly and processed automatically.

Merging is done. But the application doesn't work. Acording to the warning, I think it needs to 'key-file' or 'key-container' or '.snk key' file.
How can I find it?
Thanks.

Comment: is obfuscation mandatory for you? try [ILMerge](http://microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630) `ilmerge /target:newexe /out:c:\output.exe c:\existing.exe "C:\Users\New folder\ZedGraph.dll"`

Comment: There are two dll files in the project. One of them is own dll file. I can't give it to user. Eazfuscator.NET software uses ILMerge internally I think. Anyway, it works properly for other dll files.

Comment: I understand. I ran into similar problems when deploying VS projects without full source access to Azure. Another workaround would be to compile the ZedGraph Sources https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20source/5.1.5/zedgraph_source_v515.zip/download into your project. Or finally use MSCharting (came first as add-on with .NET3.5 and runs fine with .NET2.0)  which is in .NET4.